# Is there any way to preserve Sandbox User passwords and tokens when Sandboxes are refreshed?

Tags: sandbox-refresh, passwords

We have MANY different microservices which connect to Salesforce.
And, we have test versions for most of these, which connect to our STAGING (partial-copy).
And, for security, all our integration users have different credentials in STAGING than on production.

Obviously we need to periodically refresh out sandboxes or else it is useless because we can't test "reality" before moving our work forward.

However, when we refresh STAGING, we lose all our passwords and tokens and so we need to collect new ones and update microservices all over the place.

This is rather painful.

Is there a better way?

Comment: So you shouldn't lose the passwords, correct? They'd be the same after a refresh. In terms of tokens, I don't think you'll have much luck as they will need to be reset. However, you could look to add the IP Addresses ranges these services use as trusted IP ranges (assuming they're yours/your companies) to your network access so you don't need the security token (simply use username and password).

Comment: We want to preserve or reinstate passwords and tokens in Staging that are different from production both for security and to protect data integrity.  We might be able to use IP addresses for some of the microservices, but possibly not all of them.

Comment: Definitely misread that. The only other way to tackle it is questioning whether you obviously need to periodically refresh your sandbox (Staging, in particular). With the potential of source control and a presumed process (where everything goes to staging first) I'd hope it'd be pretty close to production with minimal effort? Might be another way to tackle this problem although I'm sure data is probably another reason you refresh and presents another issue of keeping that clean/fresh. No good answer, just food for thought

Comment: Unfortunately, for the short term, we have no CI/CD....  We HOPE to have Copado soon, but that's still being negotiated.  It is our understanding and hope that this should reduce if not eliminate the need for refreshes.... but til then, this remains a problem.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't preserve anything from the pre-refresh Sandbox. Refreshing a sandbox is semantically equivalent to deleting the old sandbox, then creating a new sandbox with the same name. The only difference between a refresh and a delete and copy is that the old Sandbox remains available while the new copy is spun up. You will need to do any post-setup each time.

Comment: Thanks for the response.... It is what I expected... but I'll leave this open for a little bit in case someone has a different answer and surprises us both.